# How to check if an array contains a value stored in a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I tried googling for the answer but at no avail. I'm new to coding  in general, c# in particular and I'm trying to get head of the game by practicing.

So, what I am trying to do is to check if an array contains / has the same value that is stored in a variable previously declared. If it has, the code will do something, if it hasn't, the code will do something else altogether. What's the easiest way to accomplish what I want to do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015.aspx

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see if a value is in the array, use `Contains` function. If you want to check whether arrays are equal use `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.structuralcomparisons.structuralequalitycomparer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int compValue = 5;
int[] values0 = { 1, 2, 5, 7, 8 };

void ContainsValue(int[] array, int valueToTest)
{
    bool isContained = array.Contains(valueToTest);
    if (isContained)
        Console.WriteLine($"{valueToTest} is in array");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"{valueToTest} is not in array");
}

void CompareArrays(int[] array, int[] arrayToTest)
{
    var comparer = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer ;
    var areEqual = comparer.Equals(array, arrayToTest);

    Console.WriteLine("-------------");
    if (areEqual)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrays are not equal");
    }
}
ContainsValue(values0, compValue);
int[] compArray1 = { 1, 2, 5, 7, 8 };
CompareArrays(values0, compArray1);
int[] compArray2 = { 1, 2, 5, 15, 8 };
CompareArrays(values0, compArray2);
CompareArrays(compArray2, values0);
}
```

And the output:

```
5 is in array
-------------
Arrays are equal
-------------
Arrays are not equal
-------------
Arrays are not equal
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like (note, I'm coming this on a phone)

```
var someVar =1;
var myArray = new [] {1, 2, 3};
bool doesItContain = myArray.Contains(someBar);
```

If you had pressed the dot after typing `myArray`, Contains would have been one of the suggestions.

Instead of staring the result in a boolean variable, you could have used directly in an `if` statement.